# Binary operator '<<' cannot be applied to two 'T' operands

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to create a generic function which can create bit mask for future usage. Here is my code:

```
import Foundation

class BitParserUtils {

    static let hexPositionOffset: Int = 4

    static func doubleHexMask<T: UnsignedInteger>(offset: Int) -> T {
        var mask: T = 0xFF
        mask = mask << ((offset * hexPositionOffset) as! T)

        return mask
    }
}
```

But I got a debug error:

```
Binary operator '<<' cannot be applied to two 'T' operands
```

I don't understand why and how to fix that. Anybody can explain me what I am doing wrong and how to fix that?

#### Example of usage

```
let maskU64: UInt64 = BitParserUtils.doubleHexMask(offset: 4)
let maskU32: UInt32 = BitParserUtils.doubleHexMask(offset: 1)
let maskU16: UInt16 = BitParserUtils.doubleHexMask(offset: 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Tomasz Wójcik already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45410712/1187415), the left shift
operator is in Swift 3 only defined for concrete integer types,
but not for the `UnsignedInteger` protocol.

A possible workaround
is to replace the left shift by a repeated multiplication:

```
func doubleHexMask<T: UnsignedInteger>(offset: Int) -> T {
    var mask: T = 0xFF
    for _ in 0..<offset {
        mask = mask &* 16
    }
    return mask
}
```

This also makes the forced cast `as! T` unnecessary. The 
["overflow operator `&*`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html) is used
here so that bits moved beyond the bounds of the integer’s storage are discarded, corresponding to what the left shift operator does.

Comment: whoa, great idea! tnx

Comment: I have a problem with overflow during multiple. `UnsignedInteger` has not `max` value. Do you have any idea how to prevent overflow?

Comment: You mean the app crashes? Maybe this article will help: https://www.uraimo.com/2016/02/05/Dealing-With-Bit-Sets-In-Swift/

Comment: @KamilHarasimowicz: Yes, the multiplication will overflow if the offset is too large. You can use `mask = mask &* 16` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use `FixedWidthInteger` instead of `UnsignedInteger`.

There is no `UnsignedInteger` overload for `<<` operator:

http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/operator/ltlt/

**Note**: this requires Xcode 9 (Swift 3.2/4.0)

Comment: You might mention that FixedWidthInteger is new in Swift 4.

Comment: Compiled using Swift 3.2.

Comment: Well, 3.2 is "almost" 4. You need Xcode 9 beta,  it does not compile with Xcode 8.3.3

Comment: Updated. Thanks for noting that.